# A good usage of HTML5's "progress" or "meter"?

Tags: html, semantics

Say you have a survey with 10 pages (one question per page). At the top of each page, you include the text, "Question 2 of 10". Is this kind of a thing a good candidate for "[progress](http://developers.whatwg.org/the-button-element.html#the-progress-element)" or "[meter](http://developers.whatwg.org/the-button-element.html#the-meter-element)"?

Semantically speaking, "progress" initially seems like the best fit. But, the more I read and look at examples, I think "meter" may be more appropriate.

```html
<meter max="10" value="1">Question 1 of 10</meter>
<progress max="10" value="1">Question 1 of 10</progress>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantically speaking, `progress` does appear to be the right thing to use here. I also posed the question to [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/), and they seemed to agree with that as well. My problem is that `progress` [is very poorly supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=progress) across the board at the moment (7/5/11). This make it very hard to use in a practical use case today.

As a stop gap, I am planning to use the convention of using the new element name as a class name in a standard div element (A.K.A. - A semantic class name). For more details, on this idea: http://jontangerine.com/log/2008/03/preparing-for-html5-with-semantic-class-names

Here's what my code will look like today. In another year or two, when this element has better support, I'll go back and replace this with real `progress` tags.

```
<div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="10">
    Question 1 of 10
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

According to the [latest HTML5 working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-progress-element), the `progress` tag is best used to display the progress of a specific task at hand. `meter` is best used for task-unrelated guages, such as disk space or memory usage.

> The `progress` element represents the
>   completion progress of a task.

Whereas

> The `meter` element represents a scalar
>   measurement within a known range, or a
>   fractional value; for example disk
>   usage, the relevance of a query
>   result, or the fraction of a voting
>   population to have selected a
>   particular candidate.

**Edit** - as rendering and styling seems to be an issue, you might have more luck using other tags. For example a sexy progress navigator could be coded with:

```
<nav class="progress">
    <ol>
        <li class="active">Your Info</li>
        <li>General</li>
        <li>Detailed</li>
        <li>Last Step</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

And styled with something [like this](http://www.dotcominfoway.com/blog/how-to-add-style-to-your-breadcrumbs-using-css).

Comment: In other words, use `progress`.

Comment: The way `<progress>` is currently implemented in Chrome it is definitely ill-suited to indicate progress in a wizard. It is animated to make sure the user doesn't get bored - which only makes sense for non-interactive tasks.

Comment: Maybe we are using different versions of Chrome? In Chromium 12 I can't see an animation.

Comment: @Wladimir: Semantically, `progress` is what should be used (that's the only conclusion I can draw from the specs). At the very least it's better than `meter`. Perhaps Webkit developers need to be informed of this perceived problem?

Comment: Great point. The animation of `progress` would look a bit strange in this instance. And styling of either of these elements is pretty spotty at the moment.

Comment: Added `<nav>` alternative to answer as it's much easier to style

Comment: I suppose `nav` would be an acceptable solution as well, as long as the contents of `nav` actually have a navigational structure.

Comment: `nav` is not the right choice here in my mind. I can see how it would work for something like breadcrumbs, as in your example, but I certainly don't want navigational elements for linking to all 10 questions in my example.

Comment: As the user progresses through the questions, that is in some way a navigation, although the HTML5 working draft does specify navigation links. I've omitted links in my example and used an ordered list to represent 1-10. I figured it was the second best, given that `progress` wasn't suitable. Interested to hear alternatives

Answer (score 3):

The `<meter>` tag defines a scalar measurement within a known range or a fractional value. This is also known as a gauge.

On Google Chrome, the resulting meter looks like this:

[image: meter1.png]

The `<progress>` tag is used to show the completion progress of a task.

On Windows 7, the resulting progress looks like this:

[image]

Note: The `<meter>` tag should not be used to indicate progress (as in a progress bar). For progress bars, use the `<progress>` tag.

Comment: these images are out of date I think or at least on my Chrome 87 on Windows the look nothing like these shots and are basically identical except one is green and the other blue

Answer (score 2):

Since this value is a determinate one, it seems "meter" would be better.
Try this reference and see if it helps:
http://peter.sh/examples/?/html/meter-progress.html

Answer (score 1):

Meters aren't supported by IE.  Not even IE10.

Answer (score -1):

Visually speaking, I think a meter is more appropriate.

Comment: "Visually speaking"? Care to explain?

Comment: Visually speaking, you should use CSS.

Comment: Reminds me of that classic Ghostbusters line, "Listen, you smell something?"

Comment: Rather, In my opinion, it looks better. And does using one of the other really matters?

Comment: @SBSTP: Sure it does. [Semantically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).