# Difference between progress tag and meter tag

Tags: html

What are the differences between the HTML5 `<progress>` and `<meter>` tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6552147/1217408

Answer (score 12):

- to mark up the completion rate ⁄ degree of progress of an "in progress" task through a progress bar, use **progress** element
- to represent a gauge use **meter** element

you can think like that: progress = dynamic ; meter = static

Answer (score 4):

As I found by my experience, the main difference between **progress** and **meter** tags is their behavior. Progress tag is viewed depending to client's OS, but meter tag is a bit stable in viewing style. Also, meter tag supports high and low values. In addition, meter tag supports connecting to forms (which is currently not available in major browsers yet).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [latest HTML5 working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-progress-element), the progress tag is best used to display the progress of a specific task at hand. meter is best used for task-unrelated guages, such as disk space or memory usage.

> The progress element represents the completion progress of a task.

where

> The meter element represents a scalar measurement within a known range, or a fractional value; for example disk usage, the relevance of a query result, or the fraction of a voting population to have selected a particular candidate.